# Default Constructor error (C++)

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

I've written a template Link list, but when I try to add an object to it I get the error "C2512 'Customer': No Appropriate default constructor available" thrown from the node constructor.

Code:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class node;

template <class T>
class l_list
{

public:
    l_list() { head = tail = NULL; }
    ~l_list();
    void add(T &obj);
    T remove(int ID);
    void print(ostream &out);

private:
    node<T> *head, *tail;
};

template <class T>
class node
{
public:
    template<class> friend class l_list;
    node() {next = NULL;}
private:
    T data;
    node *next;
};

template <class T>
l_list<T>::~l_list()
{
}

template <class T>
void l_list<T>::add(T &obj)
{
    node<T> *ptr = new node<T>;
    ptr -> data = obj;
    ptr -> next = head;
    head = ptr;

    if (tail == NULL) {tail = ptr;}
}

template <class T>
T l_list<T>::remove(int ID)
{
    int i = 0;
    node<T> * ptr = head;

    while (ptr -> data -> id != ID)
    {
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }
}

template <class T>
void l_list<T>::print(ostream &out)
{
    int i = 0;
    node<T> *ptr = head;
    while ( ptr != NULL )
    {
        out << ptr -> data << endl;
        ptr = ptr -> next;
        i++;
    }
}
```

and the object that I try and put in the list

```
l_list<Customer> customers;
Customer bob("Bob", "25 Bob Lane", "01bob82", "M", "bob/bob/bob");
customers.add(bob);
```

edit to add Customer:

```
#pragma once
#include "l_list.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Customer
{
private:
    l_list<Account> accounts;
    string name;
    string address;
    string telNo;
    string sex;
    string dob;

public:
    Customer(string name, string address, string telNo, string sex, string dob)
    {
        Customer::name = name;
        Customer::address = address;
        Customer::telNo = telNo;
        Customer::sex = sex;
        Customer::dob = dob;
    }

    void createAccount()
    {
        cout << "What type of account?";

    }

    ~Customer()
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show `Customer`?

Comment: Chances are you didn't include a default constructor in `Customer` and now `node` is trying to default-construct your `data` member.

Comment: Include this, just in case: ``Customer() {}``

Comment: I feel the need to point out that this should work if you use something like `int` instead of `Customer`.

Comment: @chris it will work for anything that supports default construction, will it not?

Comment: @WhozCraig, It's something like anything that is non-trivially constructible will be default-constructed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
node<T> *ptr = new node<T>
```

Is trying to default-construct a `T` within `node`. Since there is no default constructor, no compiley =P

You can address this by using the copy constructor (which you define or use the default one , so long as `T` properly complies with [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)) or by defining a default constructor for `T`. I prefer the former if I want to harden construct access to `T`

```
node<T> *ptr = new node<T>(obj);
```

Of course, you need to define a proper constructor for `node<T>::node(const T&)`

```
class node
{
public:
    template<class> friend class l_list;

    // T-copy-ctor-based constructor
    node(const T& obj) : data(obj), next(NULL) {};

private:
    T data;
    node *next;
};
```

Been a slow morning so sorry if I messed something up in there. =P

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the function body of void l_list::add(T &obj), since if you use the default constructor of node it also uses the default constructor of the members, i.e. T data, which is obviously not defined. Do not use the default constructor of node, but instead define a node constructor that takes an argument T& obj and initializes the member data with the reference obj. If you use only pointers to node in the linked list, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the complaint is `T data;` in your `node` class.
When you call `add`, it tries to construct a `T`, which is a `Customer`. `Customer` does not have a constructor with no arguments, so it does not work.

You could:

1. Add a default constructor (no parameters)
2. Add an assignment operator so that you can assign correctly to `data`

or

- Pass the `obj` from `add` into the constructor for `node` and initialize it correctly.

or

- Have `data` be a pointer and allocate new `Customer` objects to add.